# Property 'intercept' in type 'InterceptorErrorService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'

Tags: angular, typescript, http

Estoy tratando de implementar un interceptor HTTP en *Angular* y me aparece este error

> Property 'intercept' in type 'InterceptorErrorService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'.
>     Type '(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler) => Observable | HttpUserEvent<...>>' is not assignable to type '(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler) => Observable>'

En el código tengo esto

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorErrorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        let msg = '';

        if(error.status == 203) {
          msg = 'error en el token';
        } else {
          msg = 'sin permiso';
        }

        return msg;
      });
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te da ese error porque cualquier llamada HTTP debe devolver un `Observable<>`. En caso la llamada esté bien, el `Observable<>` resolverá en la respuesta.
En caso de error, también debe resolver en un `Observable<>`, pero esta vez un `Observable<never>`, por definición. Será un `Observable<>` que sólo emita la *callback* `onError`.

Por ello, cuando defines el operador `catchError`, se está esperando que devuelvas un `Observable<never>`, no un `string`, como en tu caso.

Para ello, puedes usar el método `throwError`, que devolverá ese `Observable<never>` y, en su `onError` resolverá aquello que le pasemos por argumento. En tu caso, el mensaje `error en el token` o `sin permiso`.

```
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        // Resolvemos el mensaje
        const message = err.status === 203
                          ? 'error en el token'
                          : 'sin permiso';

        // Devolvemos el Observable<never>
        return throwError(message);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Hacer enrutamiento en el `HttpInterceptor`

En tu misma clase que implementa el `HttpInterceptor` deberás injectar el `Router` (el servicio del *build-in* de *Angular* para hacer enrutamiento) y llamar al método `navigate` de éste.

```
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    // Inyectamos el Router
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                // ...

                // En algún punto, llamamos al navigate a la ruta que quieras.
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);

                // Y no te olvides de devolver el Observable<never>
                return throwError(...);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Por último, para que *Angular* sepa resolver el `Router` y poderlo inyectar en nuestra clase, debemos añadirlo como dependencia del *provider* en el `NgModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    // ...
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Router] // Aquí añadimos el Router como dependencia de AppInterceptor
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Excelente VRoxa! Una molestía más, tienes algún post para recomendar de como aplicarlo en mi aplicación... estoy iniciando y quiero hacer que cuando le llega uno de esos errores desde el servidor redireccione al login.. gracias desde ya

Comment: ¿Cualquier llamada HTTP? Esa redirección tendría sentido en un servicio específico de autenticación. En ese caso, valdría con inyectar el `Router`, y hacer un `... router.navigate(['/login'])`, suponiendo que *"/login"* sea tu ruta relativa al *login*. En caso de error, claro.

Comment: Sí, en caso de cualquier llamada. Por ejemplo, que quieran ingresar al /home y reciba el error del token, que significa que expiró su tiempo. Dónde debería inyectar el Router?

Comment: Tienes una pequeña explicación en el mismo post, @juan